# Calling Fortran from C++-CLI

Tags: c++-cli, fortran, linker-errors, handshaking

I have a fortran subroutine, FortranShake, and a C++ main function, HandShakingTest.cpp.
I'm trying to call a fortran subroutine from CLR C++.

I'm getting two batches of errors. Let's call them ERROR(1) and ERROR(2). I'd really appreciate if you could help me understand why these errors are happening.

When I try to compile with the following:
    cl /clr HandShakingTest.cpp

I get the following ERROR(1):

```
HandShakingTest.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00030A) "extern "C" void __c
ecl FortranShake(int &)" (?FortranShake@@$$J0YAXAAH@Z) referenced in function "int __
lrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@Sys
em@@@Z)
HandShakingTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cd
cl FortranShake(int &)" (?FortranShake@@$$J0YAXAAH@Z) referenced in function "int __c
rcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@Syst
m@@@Z)
HandShakingTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I then used the following commands to compile instead:

```
ifort /c FortranShake.f //Which compiles fine
cl /c /clr HandShakingTest.cpp //compiles fine
cl /o test HandShakingTest.obj FortranShake.obj //ERROR(2) occurs
```

ERROR(2) consists of:

```
MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(cla
ss type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(typin
fo.obj)
MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_i
nfo::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defin
ed in LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)
MSVCRT.lib(merr.obj) : error LNK2005: __matherr already defined in LIBCMT.lib(_matherr
_.obj)
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NOD
EFAULTLIB:library
HandShakingTest.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00030A) "extern "C" void __cd
ecl FortranShake(int &)" (?FortranShake@@$$J0YAXAAH@Z) referenced in function "int __c
lrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@Syst
em@@@Z)
HandShakingTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cde
cl FortranShake(int &)" (?FortranShake@@$$J0YAXAAH@Z) referenced in function "int __cl
rcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@Syste
m@@@Z)
libifcoremt.lib(for_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MAIN__ refe
renced in function _main
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Here's the HandShakingTest.cpp:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#using <System.DLL>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.DLL>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

extern "C" {void FortranShake(int&);}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Process^ testHand = gcnew Process();
    testHand->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
    testHand->StartInfo->RedirectStandardInput = true;
    testHand->StartInfo->RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    testHand->StartInfo->ErrorDialog = true;

    int numDebug = 0;
    String^ returnedDebug = "Nothing";

    FortranShake(numDebug);

    StreamReader^ FromHandProcess = testHand->StandardOutput;
    StreamWriter^ ToHandProcess = testHand->StandardInput;

    String^ Line;

    Line = FromHandProcess ->ReadLine();

    if (Line->Equals("Enter Hand") )
    {
        Console::WriteLine(L"Hand Started!");
    }
    ToHandProcess ->WriteLine(numDebug.ToString());
    returnedDebug = FromHandProcess ->ReadLine();

    MessageBox::Show(returnedDebug);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Fortran Subroutine:

```
  SUBROUTINE FortranShake(GP_DEBUG)
  IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
  INN = 5

  WRITE(06,'(a)') 'Enter Hand'

  READ(INN,*) GP_DEBUG
  GP_DEBUG = GP_DEBUG + 55
  WRITE(06,*) GP_DEBUG

  RETURN
  END
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first error is actually a linker error - without the `/c` command line switch you are compiling and linking in one step.  No Fortran code or object code has been provided.

Your second error is because:

- You have specified (through omission) mismatching runtime libraries for the C++ and the Fortran.  You need to decide whether you want to use static linking (the default for the **current** (as of today, but not necessarily as of next month...) release of Intel Fortran on windows) or dynamic linking (the default for the MS C++ compiler).  Perhaps add `/MD` to the ifort command line, which specifies dynamic linking.
- Without compiler options or directives to the contrary, the equivalent identifier for the Fortran procedure in C code as generated by that Fortran compiler is an upper case variant of the Fortran procedure's name - i.e. in the C++ code call the procedure FORTRANSHAKE.  If you can write your Fortran code to the F2003 standard, you should use the C interoperability features of that language (`BIND(C,...)`) to control the C binding name of the Fortran procedure and ensure calling conventions, etc align.
- The dummy argument of the Fortran subroutine has the DOUBLE PRECISION type specifier, which is equivalent to `double` in the C++ for this combination of compilers, not `int`.  Again, F2003 introduces features that can make this alignment of argument types more robust.